# Pattern do not accept whitespace

Tags: regex, html

I am using pattern for my input field and i want to include white space. The input should be at least 6 letters including whitespace. I used

```
pattern='\S{6,}'
```

but it only accepts letters (big or small) but not whitespace. What could be the right code?

Comment: I think you mean to tag your question as regexp rather than design-patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically matching anything but whitespace here
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Use small 's'

pattern='[\S\s]{6,}'

Comment: This actually means "either a dot or a whitespace 6+ times"

Comment: @sp00m yes, that is what Nhiz has asked for. Or did I missed something?

Comment: @sp00m . means all characters check here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: Not when within a characters class: `[.]` matches *real* dots. And you should refer to [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) instead of w3schools (see why [here](http://www.w3fools.com/) ;).

Comment: @sp00m Ok, in that case I have made the change to [\S\s]

Comment: Which is quite the same as `.` actually (`[\S\s]` matches new line chars too, but the OP seems to have a *classic single line input*).

Comment: i'e tried it. '[.\s]{6,}' only accepst white space and so i add the big S and it now works the way i wanted. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

This one should suit your needs:

```
[a-z\s]{6,}
```

Either a lowercased char or a space, 6 times or more (`\s` includes `\t` too).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be resolved by this regular expression.

```
  regex="^[\w\s]{6,}$"
```

this regex will allow all letter including whitespace with  constraint of that length must be atleast 6